# How to use cPacketQueue in my .cc file from a .msg file? | Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I try to use the "`cPacketQueue* Fmqueue`" or "`Fmqueue DFrameQueue`" in my .cc file because of its "`insert()`" and "`send()`" functions. But i don't know how to call this packet DownFrame the right way.
I can use `queue->getFrameSize()` but not something like "`getDFrameQueue()`".

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
//DownstreamFrame.msg
cplusplus{{
#include <omnetpp.h>
typedef cPacketQueue* Fmqueue;
}}
class noncobject Fmqueue;

packet DownFrame
{
   Fmqueue DFrameQueue;
   int FrameSize = 155520;
}

//in my OLT.cc file i can all the FrameSize() but no Fmqueue DFrameQueue
DownFrame *queue = new DownFrame();
FrameQueueSize = queue -> getFrameSize();
```